# After login Ubuntu displays a blue screen after I tried to install Visual Studio Code

Tags: login

When the Ubuntu login page is loading there is no black ribbon as previously, but I can log in. After that though, a blue screen appears. If I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>CLT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> the blue screen remains.

What can I do?

It worked this morning without any problem. I was trying to install Visual Studio Code and then I restarted it. Then the error appeared.